# Spring Boot REST one-to-one - POST or PUT?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, rest, spring-rest

I am developing Spring Boot REST api, and now I have encountered some `logical problem`.

So I have an entity "A" that owns one-to-one relationship with entity "B".
Initialy, entity "A" is POSTed with without entity "B" (-> so relationship is null).

**So when I want to add entity "B" should I simply POST it, or PUT/PATCH entity "A" with entity "B"?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider an entity's A and B and taken the firstName and lastName field:

```
@Entity
public class A {

    @Id
    private Integer id;

    private String firstName;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "a")
    private B b; 
}

@Entity
public class B {

    @Id
    private Integer id;
 
    private String lastName;

    @OneToOne
    private A a;
}
```

Repositories are:

```
@Repository 
 public interface ARepo extends JpaRepository<A,Integer> {
}
@Repository
 public interface BRepo extends JpaRepository<B,Integer> {
}
```

let's use @postContruct to save some data in A entity

```
@PostConstruct
void init(){
    A a = new A(1,"ABCD");
    aRepo.save(a);
}
```

controller for saving B Entity:

```
 @PostMapping("/saveB")
 public String save(@RequestBody B b){
    bRepo.save(b);
    return "ok";
 }
```

and json for saving the B Entity:

{
"id":1,
"lastName":"xyz",
"a":{
"id":1
}
}

For my understanding, if we save the entity from the B Repository we need to use the @PostMapping(a new row is inserted), or we can use the A repository to save the B entity because here mapping is Bidirectional, by using @PutMapping(already A data exits in database, we need to update it by adding B's data)

Answer (score 0):

There is no relation between persisting an entity in a DB using an ORM such as `Hibernate` and `POST/PUT/PATCH` which are `HTTP` verbs. Please don't get confused.

Assuming you have entity A and B defined as a one-to-one bidirectional association(by default the association's(One-to-One in this case) `optional` attribute is true):

```
@Entity
public class A implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7174277851973636756L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "a") //If you add optional = false, it will not work
    B b;

    //And so on
}


@Entity
public class B implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6581935686158784727L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id") //You need this, else it will look for "a_id" column(foreign_key) in Class/Table B.
    A a;

   //And so on
}
```

And ARepository and BRepository as follows:

```
public interface ARepository extends CrudRepository<A, Long> {

}

public interface BRepository extends CrudRepository<B, Long> {

}
```

You can simply do first:

```
@Autowired
private ARepository aRepository;

A a = new A();
aRepository.save(a);
```

And later:

```
@Autowired
private BRepository bRepository;

B b = new B();
bRepository.save(b);
```

The equivalent SQLs:

```
insert 
into
    a
    (id) 
values
    (?)

insert 
into
   b
    (id) 
values
    (?)
```

Note:
If the entity already exist, `save` will do an `update` instead of an `insert`, but since we are using an auto-generated id, it will always do an `insert`.